# advanced search with OR condition in magento

Tags: magento

I want to search with the advanced form, but with an mysql OR statement instead of AND statement.

For example I search for product ‘A’ in **Product name** field and ‘B’ in **Product Type** field. The search results has to be A OR B.

and i also change the condition

System > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Catalog Search > Search Type

search Type = LIKE

but thats not work so Is there other way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite in a custom module

`Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Advanced_Collection`

(\app\code\core\Mage\CatalogSearch\Model\Resource\Advanced\Collection.php)

and replace by the end of the `addFieldsToFilter` method (line 132 on Magento 1.7.0.2)

```
if (!is_null($previousSelect)) {
    $select->where('t1.entity_id IN (?)', new Zend_Db_Expr($previousSelect));
}
```

by

```
if (!is_null($previousSelect)) {
    $select->orWhere('t1.entity_id IN (?)', new Zend_Db_Expr($previousSelect));
}
```

Using `orWhere` instead of `where` will add next conditions as OR to the query.

I haven't tested it so much so maybe there are tricks depending on the attribute type but it seems to work great with text attributes.

**UPDATE** for dropdown attributes you need to extend (or modify for testing purposes) `Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Advanced` and change `addIndexableAttributeModifiedFilter` method at line 191 on Magento 1.7.0.2

```
$select->where("{$tableAlias}.value IN(?)", $value);
```

by

```
$select->orWhere("{$tableAlias}.value IN(?)", $value);
```

Note that this is far from a complete solution as it wont work when mixing texts and dropdonws. Achieving complete OR should be slightly more complex as you probably have to check for existing conditions when adding filters.

Cheers

Comment: As I said the method above has only been tested for text attributes. When you use dropdowns only, it doesnt event get into `Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Advanced_Collection`. So there's definitely something wrong with your attributes. First you should make sure that regular search works well on your site with dropdowns.

Comment: That beeing said, you can achieve that OR condition for dropdowns by modifying `Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Advanced`. I'll update my answer.